# How to subsitute <noscript> in a href tag with javascript activated by onclick

Tags: javascript, html, noscript

I have a question about retrofitting the following code to gracefully handle noscript scenario.

```
Call me <a href="" onclick="activateContact(); return false;" unselectable="on"> <span>My Contact</span> </a>
```

I'd like to subsitute the line above in case of noscript with:

```
Call me at 1-800-555-1525.
```

Thanks in advace.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Pretty much I have two lines: one with the actual href containing js, and <noscript>Call me at 1-800-555-1525</noscript> below.

Comment: You have to do it the other way round: replace the noscript through javascript with the content you want

Comment: How then to display Call me My Contact? Where should the message be put?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**script** tag is used for javaScript. Same way there is  tag which gets in action when the Javascript is diabled in browser. So to substitute your anchor with noscript data when JS is disbaled in browser. Use this

```
<script>
  Call me <a href="" onclick="activateContact(); return false;" unselectable="on"> 
  <span>My Contact</span> </a>
</script>


<noscript>
    Call me at 1-800-555-1525. 
</noscript>
```

Comment: Hm, for me the content of <script>...</script> is not recognized by the browser. Even if I set the type of the script:
<script type="text/html">...</script>

Answer (score 2):

Set the link to noscript behavior:

```
 Call me at <a  id="callMeLink" href="#" unselectable="on"> <span>1-800-555-1525.</span> </a>
```

Then do the progressive enhancement with js. If the js is not activated in browser, the link above will be on the right format already.

```
<script>
   var callMeLink = document.getElementById("callMeLink");
   callMeLink.onclick = activeContact;
   callMeLink.innerHTML = "<span>My Contact</span>";
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you devundef. This worked for me. I put your script into the head, so I had to make shure that the element is loaded already. So I put everything into  window.onload = function() {...}